# Python's AHK check for image_search value not work

Tags: python

I tried AHK module on Python and using image_search() (I tried pyautogui locateOnScreen too but it's slower than AHK).

Here my little code I made:

```
location = ahk.image_search('images/example.png')
print(location)
if location == 'None':
    print('nono')
else:
    pyautogui.moveTo(location)
    ahk.click()
    print('clicked')
```

Log:

```
C:\>py -3 testing.py
None
clicked
```

I'm using 'if' to check the 'location' value is 'None' but seem like it just doesn't work and continue to work normal meanwhile the value was 'None'.

I tried to search that problem but can't figure it out.

**UPDATE:** by using the power of comment section, here the working code

```
location = ahk.image_search('images/example.png')
print(location)
if location is None:
    print('nono')
else:
    pyautogui.moveTo(location)
    ahk.click()
    print('clicked')
```

I should learn Python basic again..

Comment: Check the type of `location`.

Comment: If the image can be found, the value return `(1485, 465)`, how can I check

Comment: I was hinting at, it may not be a string.  `print(type(location))`